# Google Sheets count consecutive dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

I have a Google Sheet with a list of dates & times like this:

```
10/24/2019 4:25:00
10/29/2019 4:33:22
10/30/2019 4:33:11
10/31/2019 4:24:11
11/1/2019 4:36:11
11/2/2019 5:21:37
11/4/2019 5:30:20
11/6/2019 5:21:28
11/7/2019 5:27:07
11/8/2019 5:22:34
11/10/2019 8:51:13
11/11/2019 5:26:27
11/11/2019 11:41:27
11/12/2019 5:27:49
11/13/2019 5:30:34
```

I am looking for a way to figure out the longest "streak" of consecutive dates where there was at least one entry.  The data can be unsorted or sorted.

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution without google app scripts

1) sort your unique dates

```
=arrayformula(query(unique(datevalue(A:A)),"select * where Col1 is not null"))
```

2) mark the days that are streak days with a 1

```
=arrayformula(if(F:F="","",{0;if(F2:F-F1:F=1,1,0)}))
```

3) count the streaks

```
=max(arrayformula(if(G:G="","",frequency(if(G:G,row(G:G)),if(not(G:G),row(G:G))))))
```

Note: in my example column A is the original dates, column F is my sorted dates, column G is my streak marker. You can also combine step 2 and 3 into one bigger formula `=arrayformula(frequency(if(if(F:F="","",{0;if(F2:F-F1:F=1,1,0)}),sequence(rows(if(F:F="","",{0;if(F2:F-F1:F=1,1,0)})))),if(not(if(F:F="","",{0;if(F2:F-F1:F=1,1,0)})),sequence(rows(if(F:F="","",{0;if(F2:F-F1:F=1,1,0)}))))))`

Comment: I had to add a +1 to the formula in step 3 to get the total number of days that were in the streak, but other than that it worked well, thanks!

Comment: @TonyRanieri yes it depends on if you consider the first day a streak or not, if I defined it that way then everyday by definition would be a "1 streak".

Answer (score 1):

You could create a google app script function like this:

```
function BIGGEST_CONSECUTIVE_DATE_STREAK() {
  const activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const range = activeSheet.getActiveRange();
  var currentDate;
  var newDate;
  var biggestStreak = 0;
  var currentStreak = 0; 

  // Loop through all values in the selected range
  for (i = 0; i < range.getValues().length - 2; i++) {
    currentDate = new Date(range.getValues()[i])
    newDate = new Date(range.getValues()[i+1])

    if (currentDate.getMonth == newDate.getMonth) {  
      if (newDate.getDate() - currentDate.getDate() == 1) {
        // If dates are consecutive in terms of days, 
        // the consecutive date streak increases.
        currentStreak++;
      } else {
        // Otherwise the streak ends.
        currentStreak = 0;
      }
    }
    // Update the biggest number of consecutive days.
    if (currentStreak > biggestStreak) biggestStreak = currentStreak;  
  } 
  // Alert the biggest consecutive date streak. 
  // Change this line depening on your use case.
  Browser.msgBox(biggestStreak, Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
}
```

I presumed you meant by 'consecutive dates' consecutive as in days.

**Usage**: select the dates in google sheets and execute this script.

[Go here for the documentation on how to create a custom function and link it to your google sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) if you don't know how to execute the script.